# How would I replace the question mark with slashes? [PHP]

Tags: php

I've been looking around for a while now but I couldn't find anything that worked and it's stumped me for a while now. I was wondering how I can convert question marks to slashes.

Example:

`mywebsite.com/news.php?id=test-title`

How would I convert this to:

`mywebsite.com/news.php/id/test-title`

Many thanks in advance! :) (Sorry if not enough info was given. First time posting. LMK if you need more.)

Comment: why is this post upvoted?? Anyway what you need is htaccess re-write. google that!

Answer (score 0):

You want **url rewriting**.

example (place this code as *.htaccess* file under root of your application) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

There are several rules you can apply depending on your situation, I suggest you read about it.

Answer (score -1):

Try [str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)
It lets you find a specific value inside a string for your case a website URL.
You can then change a certain value in the string to a new one. 
For example I want to change my name Aidan to my middle name John,

```
<?php echo str_replace("Aidan", "John", "Hello my name is Aidan"); ?>
```

The output would be `Hello my name is John` it replaces Aidan in the original string to John.

In your case, it is pretty simple `<?php echo str_replace("?", "/", "mywebsite.com/news.php?id=test-title "); ?>` Outputs to `mywebsite.com/news.php/id=test-title`

Comment: OP needs htaccess re-write. not this!

Comment: why'd you give the same answer I've given? Also, you can see my answer is downvoted by someone. Don't you think different answer is required for this?